# TeamCity Support with Git and MSysGit Public/Private Keys

Tags: teamcity

Does anyone know if TeamCity 5 support the SSH keys generated by using Msysgit? I am not able to connect TeamCity to github using the keys generated by msysgit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does work.

See [TeamCity GitHub Private Key Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376678/teamcity-github-private-key-access-denied) for the required VCS Root configuration settings.

Comment: yeah i got it running. It was some space or return in the public/private keys.