# TeamCity GitHub Private Key Access Denied

Tags: windows, teamcity, github

Does anyone know of a tutorial for using TeamCity with github with ssh private keys.  I have tried to set up git hub to connect and I either get a authentication error or get access denied.  I am running TeamCity on Windows 2003.  I am running the build agent as a custom account.  I am running the web server under the administrator account.  I have create a key for the custom account and administrator account.  I now get an error that:

**The connection test failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.ssh (Access is denied)**

If anyone has successfully set this up please help.  I am going on 3 hours into this and want to get it solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following VCS Root configuration works for me:

- Clone URL: git@github.com:username/repository.git
- Clone repository to: C:\somepath
- User Name Style: UserId (jsmith)
- Authentication Method: Private Key
- Private Key Path: C:\SSH\myKeyFile.priv
- Passphrase: only if key file is secured with a passphrase

Comment: This works for me as well, however if you want to do an agent-based checkout, you need to use the "Default private key" instead of a private key path.  I haven't been able to get that working yet (on windows). Any ideas?  Doesn't seem to honor my ~/.ssh/config file at all.

Comment: Found it... I needed to specify a wildcard for the hostname, so my file looks like this:
Host *
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/toms_desktop_id_rsa

Comment: when using private key to authenticate I did not need to add my username at all

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't figured this out yet...

### this config worked out for me

Authentication Method: Default Private Key

UserName: (blank)

Known Hosts Database <<-- **CHECK IT!**

thats what finally worked after a couple 
of hours trying to get it to work :)

Comment: what do you mean by "check it" next to the known hosts database?